# Update ConEmu tab with current path

Tags: powershell, conemu

On ConEmu I'm opening a powershell console. I'd like the title of the tab to reflect the current folder I'm in. However, by default, the title is "Windows Powershell."

I specified the tab title in my task to be "C:\Code" and it updates, but that is hard coded.

Is there a way to open a powershell console, and as I navigate have it show me the current directory in the tab title?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**PowerShell**

Change `prompt` function in your powershell profile.

Open your profile in the editor, Notepad for example

```
new-item -itemtype file -path $profile
notepad $profile
```

Add following function to change (rename actually) ConEmu tab each time prompt appears

```
function prompt
{
  & "$env:ConEmuBaseDir\ConEmuC.exe" "/GUIMACRO", 'Rename(0,@"'$(Get-Location)'")' > $null
  return "PS " + $(Get-Location) + ">"
}
```

or use following code to change console title, but not tab

```
function prompt
{
  & "$env:ConEmuBaseDir\ConEmuC.exe" "/GUIMACRO", 'Rename(1,@"'$(Get-Location)'")' > $null
  return "PS " + $(Get-Location) + ">"
}
```

May be need to change this code, if you need to use PowerShell outside of ConEmu.

---

**cmd (let it be in one answer)**

If you are using `cmd.exe`, you may update ConEmu tab with cmd's current directory using `prompt` and [ANSI](http://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/wiki/AnsiEscapeCodes). Just run your cmd as following:

```
cmd /k prompt $p$e]9;3;"$p"$e\$g & title cmd
```

To be able to process ANSI you need to enable `Inject ConEmuHk` and `ANSI X3.64` options in the ConEmu's `Features` settings page (they are enabled by default). RightClick on the ConEmu's window title or press <kbd>Win</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> to open `Settings` dialog.

Note, `& title cmd` in the example is not required, just for prettify window caption.

Comment: With latest version you may use `%d` macro in the tab template. However, may be you need to configure your shell https://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/wiki/ShellWorkDir